# Hide Zend radio button & checkbox labels in javascript click handler

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, label, dom-events, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend radio buttons and checkboxes in my form, but some of them have to be hidden, when the user clicks other values. Regarding to this I wrote a click handler where I'm able to hide the radio button/checkbox by itself, but not the corresponding label.
The radio buttons are initialized like this:

```
    $gender = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('gender', array('escape' => false) );
    $gender->setLabel('Gender')
        ->addMultiOptions(array(
                            'f' => 'female',
                            'm' => 'male'))
        ->setDecorators(array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Errors',
            array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd') ),
            array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt', 'escape' => false, 'class' => 'question') )
            ))
        ->setRequired(true);
    $gender_required_checkbox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('gender_required_checkbox');
    $gender_required_checkbox->setAttrib('required', 'required');
    $gender->setAttribs(array('onClick'=>'required_check_clckHndlr(this)'));
```

The Javascript click handler looks like this:

```
    $("#gender").hide('slow');
    $("#gender-label").hide('slow');
    $("#gender_required_checkbox").hide('slow');
    $("#gender_required_checkbox-label").hide('slow');
```

This works fine for the radio buttons and the checkboxes, but the labels are still shown

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem a few day's back while I tried to use

```
$('label[for="checkbox"]').hide();
```

without success. So I ended up using the `.parent()` jquery method to iterate trough my DOM and then `.hide()` the whole block instead.

```
$('#your_id').parent().parent().hide();
```

Comment: I tried your first approach and changed it a little bit. In the end I had to do this for every label of a radio button/checkbox:  `$('[for=gender-f]').hide('slow');`